# CSRF protection in depth

Tags: php, security, csrf, csrf-protection

I currently add a CSRF token protection mechanism to my php application.
As I read, the only requirement is a unique per-user token, which I generate using random_bytes in php7.

My concern is, if the attacker sends a http request using the user's browser, won't the browser send the session variable of the token in anyway? (because the user has the sessionid associated with the token).

I store the token inside a hidden value echo'd from the session variable.

For example: my token is stored inside a session variable and then the attacker sends me to a change password page with csrf protection, the validation will not pass? (I already have the correct session identifier in my browsers cookies).

Thanks

Comment: If you are storing tokens on the client side (e.g. in a cookie) or you're storing it server-side in the session array, but all that is required of the client is the session ID, you're doing it wrong. The token should be put as a hidden field into any and all forms on your website that perform an action that you wouldn't want to be repeated or mimicked by an attacker. See https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/csrf-attacks/

Comment: Also, the other requirement is: Use HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how a CSRF attack works:

Alice (wittingly or unwittingly) visits `compromised.com`

`compromised.com` makes an HTTP post† request to `yoursite.com`, using an HTML form, or JavaScript, or Flash or whatever can make an HTTP post request.

```
<form method=post action="http://yoursite.com/change-password">
  <input name=password value=666>
  <input name=confirm_password value=666>
</form>
```

This works because the web browser will send Alice's `yoursite.com` session cookie to `yoursite.com`.

Due to the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), `compromised.com` **can send** any data it wants to any site, but **cannot read** data from other sites.

Here's how CSRF protection works:

`yoursite.com` demands an HTTP post request variable called `_csrf_token` (or similar) and compares it to what you have stored for Alice in *server-side* session memory.

You write `_csrf_token`'s value into a hidden input in your HTML forms, so it is automatically sent with form posts from `yoursite.com`

`compromised.com` *cannot read* the value of `_csrf_token` from `yoursite.com` due to the Same-origin policy, so its attempts to post to `yoursite.com` will fail.

```
<form method=post action="http://yoursite.com/change-password">
  <input name=password value=666>
  <input name=confirm_password value=666>
  <input name=_csrf_token value="???">
</form>
```

† it doesn't have to be post, but that's common

Comment: Exactly what I needed. it means that a simple echo from the session storage and verification will prevent CSRF well enough? Thank you!

Comment: Yup, just write the csrf token value from session into your html forms, and check it against the value in session memory when a user tries to submit a form.